# Warning: No client method with the name 'userjoined' found in signalR

Tags: asp.net, .net, websocket, signalr

I'm trying to create a multiplayer chat web app, when a user joins a room, i need to send message to the other users that the user has joined but for some reason the message is being sent to current user who joined the room as well I used **OthersInGroup** to make sure it doesn't get sent to the current user.

[the log message when first joined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDjzB.png)

when i refresh the page, i get

`No client method with the name 'userjoined' found in signalR` error in my console

[log message after some refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktxnw.png)

RoomHub.cs

```
// ChatHub.cs
using System.Text.Json;
using GuessMySketch.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

public class RoomHub : Hub
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public RoomHub(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string roomId, string message)
    {
        await Clients.OthersInGroup(roomId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public async Task SendCanvasData(Coordinate originalPosition, Coordinate newPosition, string activeColor, string roomId)
    {
        await Clients.OthersInGroup(roomId).SendAsync("ReceiveCanvasData", new CanvasData { originalPosition = originalPosition, newPosition = newPosition, activeColor = activeColor });
    }

    public async Task ClearData(string roomId)
    {
        await Clients.OthersInGroup(roomId).SendAsync("ClearCanvas");
    }

    public async Task NextRound(string roomId)
    {
        await Clients.Group(roomId).SendAsync("ClearCanvas");
    }


    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
        var roomId = httpContext.Request.Cookies["room"].ToString();
        var username = httpContext.Request.Cookies["user"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(username);

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
        await Clients.OthersInGroup(roomId).SendAsync("UserJoined", username);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        // await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
        // Perform actions when a user disconnects
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
public class Coordinate
{
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
}

public class CanvasData
{
    public Coordinate originalPosition { get; set; } = null!;
    public Coordinate newPosition { get; set; } = null!;
    public string activeColor { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using GuessMySketch.Data;
using GuessMySketch.DTO;
using GuessMySketch.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    }));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoomRepo, RoomRepo>();

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase")));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<RoomHub>("/room", options =>
    {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
    });
});

app.MapPost("/createRoom", async (HttpContext context, IRoomRepo repo, [FromBody] CreateRoomDto createRoomDto) =>
{

    SessionReadDto session = await repo.CreateRoom(createRoomDto.name);

    if (session != null && session.Data != null)
    {
        // Set the JSON string as a cookie value
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("room", session.Data.Code, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), Secure = true, HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });

        context.Response.Cookies.Append("user", session.Data.Username.ToString(), new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), Secure = true, HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });



        return Results.Created($"/users/{session.Data.Code}", session.Data.Code);
    }
    else if (session != null && session.Message != null)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest(new { error = session.Message });
    }

    return Results.BadRequest(new { error = "something went wrong" });
});

app.MapPost("/joinRoom", async (HttpContext context, IRoomRepo repo, [FromBody] JoinRoomDto joinRoomDto) =>
{

    SessionReadDto session = await repo.JoinRoom(joinRoomDto);

    if (session != null && session.Data != null)
    {

        // Set the JSON string as a cookie value
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("room", session.Data.Code, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), Secure = true, HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });

        context.Response.Cookies.Append("user", session.Data.Username.ToString(), new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), Secure = true, HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });

        return Results.Created($"/users/{session.Data.Code}", session.Data.Code);
    }
    else if (session != null && session.Message != null)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest(new { error = session.Message });
    }

    return Results.BadRequest(new { error = "something went wrong" });
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Room.jsx:

```
 const [connection, setConnection] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function makeConnection() {
      const socketConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
        .withUrl('http://localhost:5028/room', {
          skipNegotiation: true,
          transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .build()
      await socketConnection.start()
      setConnection(socketConnection)
    }
    makeConnection()
  }, [])

  connection &&
    connection.on('UserJoined', (message) => {
      console.log(message)
    })
```

if there is any issue in my setup please let me know as i have trying to debug this for a while

I tried using other methods like GroupExcept and console log the connectionId

Comment: `connection.on('UserJoined', ...)` has to be called before `connection.start()` to not get the warning. The handlers need to be added before the connection is started.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I was able to fix the warning thanks for that, but the UserJoined event is still getting emitted to the current user even with using OthersInGroup, also the UserJoined is triggered multiple times for the other user who were already in the room. [image](https://imgur.com/a/uLg4iGF)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's the issue, turns out I was trying to make multiple connections with the way i have the web sockets setup in react.

I changed it to something like the one below and everything worked:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const socketConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl('http://localhost:5028/room', {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .build()
    setConnection(socketConnection)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
      connection.on('UserJoined', (message) => {
        console.log(message)
      })
      connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log('connected')
      })
    }
  }, [connection])
```